# Two click events tied to one element

Tags: jquery

I have a anchor tag which has a img tag inside. when I click on the img, an event happens. However, I have another click event tagged to the anchor tag as well, so how do I prevent the click event on the anchor click on the img click?

```
<a class="rfi btn btn-inverse"><img class="delete"/></a>
```

my click events are done using jquery.

Answer (score 2):

Stop the click on the image from bubbling up and triggering its parent's click handler:

```
$("img").on("click", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You do that by stopping "propagation" (bubbling) from the `img` to the `a`, via [`Event#stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/). So:

```
$("selector for your img elements").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    // -- Your img click code here --
});
```

(`return false` from the event handler will also do it, but will *also* prevent any default action. Mind you, there is no default action for `click` on an `img` element, so it would be fine in this case.)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$("your img selector").click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: When you post an answer and see that it's ended just being an exact duplicate of previous answers, it's best to delete your answer.